# JS $scope.something equals to a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't understand what $scope.search is doing there, like, what it is doing when it set equals to the function? And, if i want to do in other way, how should i do?
(i am using angular js, 1.6 version)

```
 $scope.search = function(){
                    query.get($scope.username , {
                        success: function(gameScore) {
                            console.log(gameScore);
                            return gameScore;
                        },
                        error: function(object, error) {
                            console.log("Sorry, this user does not exist yet");
                        }
                    });
                };
```

Comment: See [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35329384/5535245)

Comment: The $scope property named `search` is being assigned a reference to an anonymous function. See [MDN JavaScript Reference - function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `$scope.search()` from anywhere in your controller. You can also do something like `ng-click=search()` on any element in a template that is using that controller.

Calling `$scope.search()` will either return `gameScore` or print an error message to the console.

Comment: but if i remove it, and let just  the function() an error occurs

Comment: You can't just have a stand alone function, it needs to be set to something.

Comment: Actually calling that function will never `return` anything

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this function is written in a general controller or a component controller
Since you are using 1.6
Incase of it being a component controller you could attach this function to component controller and use it in your template or component

```
angular.module('app',[])
.component('testComponent', {
    bindings: {}.
    tempalate:'<div>$ctrl.getValue()</div>',
    controller: function(){
       var ctrl = this;
       ctrl.getValue = function() {
       console.log('log your value');
    }
  }
});
```